# I want to join a multiple choice quiz to my python project in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am building an app that will contain many quizzes. I set up the first quiz on a python file and I have the main project on another python and kv file (I am using kivy and kivy language). Now I don’t know how to put the created quiz in its place in the main project. I tried making a class for the quiz and then inheriting from it in the class where I want it to be in my main project but it didn’t work

This is the quiz I created:

```
from Question import Question

question_prompts = [
    "What color is an egg?\n(a) White\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
    "What comes after b?\n(a) A\n(b) V\n(c) C\n\n",
    "Which of these is a color?\n(a) Teal\n(b) Magneta\n(c) Yellow\n\n"
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "c"),
]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + "correct")


run_test(questions)
```

And this is the class where I want it to be in the main project:

```
class NineteenWindow(Screen):

   pass
```

And this is the part of the kv file I have for that class:

```
<NineteenWindow>
    name: "this"
```

What can I add in the NineteenWindow class to be able to import the quiz there?

Answer (score 0):

according to what I understand from your question - you want to include a `.py` & `.kv` file into another file. If yes, then the here's how you can do it.

1. To `import` a python file to `main.py`

   from pythonfilename import classyouwant
2. To `import` a kivy file to `main.py`

   Builder.load_file('yourkivyfile.kv')

**Things to remember**

1. You need to `import` the Builder `from kivy.lang import Builder`
2. Do not create the main function in the files which are being imported to the `main.py`

Comment: I did this but I got the quiz in the run terminal and then the code stopped going further. I want it to be on screens and visible when I click the correct button that should lead me to the quiz.

Comment: I posted the full code and screenshot in my recent post!